# Tapestry - How to pass parameters from tml page to event handler in tapestry?

Tags: java, parameters, parameter-passing, tapestry

I am new to tapestry. Can someone help me on following issue I am having hard time solving?

I have a form in my page tags.tml

```
<div class="tagForm" id="addTagFormElement" style="display:none;">
    <t:form t:id="addTagForm" t:zone="tagsZone" class="hideForReadOnlyMode addTagForm" style="display:inline-block;">
        <t:textfield t:id="newTag" t:mixins="salsaautocomplete" size="25" placeholder="add a tag" validate="required" value="newTag" />     
    </t:form>
</div>
```

When this form is submitted, following method is called on the server side java class tags.java

```
Object onSuccessFromAddTagForm() {      
      // some logic
}
```

I want to know how can I pass a parameter(say "testParameter") from tml file to this method which is invoked when the form is submitted. 
I would like to do something like below.

```
<div class="tagForm" id="addTagFormElement" style="display:none;">
    <t:form t:id="addTagForm" t:zone="tagsZone" t:testParameter="testValue" class="hideForReadOnlyMode addTagForm" style="display:inline-block;">
        <t:textfield t:id="newTag" t:mixins="salsaautocomplete" size="25" placeholder="add a tag" validate="required" value="newTag" />     
    </t:form>
</div>
```

And access it in method like,

```
Object onSuccessFromAddTagForm(String testParameter) {      
      // some logic
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `context` parameter of [form](http://tapestry.apache.org/5.3/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/Form.html). You can pass a single parameter or multiple parameters (using `context='[param1, param2]'`) and then in the submit handler you can use

```
Object onSubmitFromMyForm(Object param1, Object param2){
....
}
```

Please note, the parameters are type coerced.

Comment: How can we set values of these parameters which are mentioned in context ? I want to be able to send these parameters with values to the handler. And access it there. Can you show how to set values of parameters in tml file and access them in handler method?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "set values of these parameters" ?

Comment: @Tawus: you state it like this: <t:form context="literal:my happy value">. read about binding expressions in the docs: http://tapestry.apache.org/component-parameters.html#ComponentParameters-BindingExpressions